# Count pattern in a given string with Python

Tags: string, python-2.7, pattern-matching

I have this sheet of python code

```
import re
def smallestPat(s):
   r = re.compile(r"(.+?)\1+")
   for match in r.finditer(s):
       return match.group(1)

case = input()
for i in xrange(case):
    stringAll = raw_input()
    pattern = smallestPat(stringAll)
    print len(pattern)
```

This code is fine for repeated pattern like

> abab
>
> abababababababababab
>
> abababababab

Output :

> 2
>
> 2
>
> 2

However, If I enter the following string as input :

> abc

I get an error.
And the output which I am looking for is:

> 3

I need help ! thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? And what does the output signify?

Comment: I want to determine the pattern that its characters can generate a string input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is "abc" regex couldn't find a matching string so it returns `None` and `len(None)` raises an exception.

Changing the regex to `(.+?)(\1+|$)` should help.